# How to display css multiple columns with dynamic height

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I am displaying template to show it on monitor.

I have designed layout like this:

[image]

But I want to display like this (to save the space):

[image]

My code looks like this :

```js
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

$scope.businessObject =
    [
    {
        CompanyName: "AA",
        StockWaringItemsCount: 0,
        Items: [
       {
           ToolNumber: "200", ItemName: "Item 1 GREY", UOM: "PCs", MinStockLevel: 100, Stock: 5000
       }
        ]
    },
      {
          CompanyName: "BB",
          StockWaringItemsCount: 1,
          Items: [
       { ToolNumber: "111", ItemName: "Item 1", UOM: "", MinStockLevel: 200, Stock: 150 },
       { ToolNumber: "222", ItemName: "Item 2", UOM: "", MinStockLevel: 300, Stock: 400 },
       { ToolNumber: "333", ItemName: "Item 3", UOM: "", MinStockLevel: 400, Stock: 200 },
          ]
      },
     {
         CompanyName: "AutoLive",
        StockWaringItemsCount: 1000,
         Items: [
     { ToolNumber: "111", ItemName: "Item 222", UOM: "", MinStockLevel: 500, Stock: 5000 },
      { ToolNumber: "222", ItemName: "Item 444", UOM: "", MinStockLevel: 600, Stock: 5000 },
       { ToolNumber: "333", ItemName: "Item 252", UOM: "", MinStockLevel: 700, Stock: 5000},
          ]
      }
    ];
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="company in businessObject" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-hover btn-info">{{company.CompanyShortID}}</a>
              <div class="pull-right">
                    <div ng-show="company.StockWarnigItemsCount>0">
                        <span class="badge" style="color: Red">{{company.StockWarnigItemsCount}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle" ng-show="company.StockWarnigItemsCount===0">
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <table class="table table-condensed" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Tool
                            </th>
                            <th style="width: 60%">
                                Item
                            </th>
                            <th style="text-align: center">
                                Min
                            </th>
                            <th style="text-align: center">
                                Stock
                            </th>
                            <th style="text-align: center">
                                Status
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in company.Items">
                        <td>
                            {{item.ToolNumber}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{item.ItemName}}
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right">
                            {{item.MinStockLevel}}
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right">
                            {{item.Stock}}
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                           

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

i am using angularjs with bootstrap.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post some code, not only links, please.

Comment: Ditch the table layout, make two bootstrap-like column and place your tables inside them. If you want the to collapse in the reading order, then that'll be a different problem.

Comment: @gskema : please could you elaborate it.

Comment: @nk1 Yo achieve the layout in the picture, you would have to make left column (`50%, col-sm-6`) and a right column (`50%, col-sm-6`). But the problem is that you're using `ng-repeat`, which outputs every item at once, you can't differentiate which columnit goes to. I'm not an angular expert, maybe that's achievable somehow, but is it worth it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed ng-repeat.

I have used masonry jquery. appended items dynamically(as mentioned in masonry document). Now it is working perfectly fine!..

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left` to the `CSS` of these elements. 
However, it will still depend on the order of the elements if they will appear the way you showed it (you might have to change the order - in this case the order is top let, lower left, topright, lower right)